# Is it possible to access specific query variables during a graphQL execution?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, graphql

Using graphQL, let's say my query is

```
{
  client(clientId: 1) {
    clientId 
    address 
    DoB 
  }
}
```

This will return the `clientId`, `address` and `DoB` of the user with a clientId of 1. When defining the function to resolve this query, I query my DB (DynamoDb). When I query dynamo, I can specify which attributes to return. But, as of now, I cannot get graphQL to tell me which attributes the original query contained. Is it possible to access an object that contains the original query variables (clientId, address and DoB), which I can then pass onto the dynamo query? Doing this, obviously, will reduce network load and also make the API more dynamic.

Logic of what is happening now:

Client says to API, return {clientId, address, DoB} -> API says to Dynamo return all attributes of client with specific clientId -> Dynamo returns all attributes -> graphQL API resolves and returns only {clientId, address, DoB}

Logic of what I want to happen:

Client says to API return {clientId, address, DoB} -> API says to Dynamo return {clientId, address, DoB} -> Dynamo returns {clientId, address, DoB} -> graphQL API resolves and returns {clientId, address, DoB}

Let me know if anyone knows if graphQL can do this intrinsically. Otherwise, I'll have to build a wrapper function.

Comment: I'd be curious about any intrinsic capabilities of graphql-js, but if you don't find that, I feel like facebook/dataloader might help out... the idea being to fetch nothing at the user level (simply return ~`{id: '1'}`), then call dataloader or wrapper function at the field level, relying on dataloader for the aggregating of DB calls, and your wrapper function for capturing the desired fields.

Answer (score 0):

This was important to me because some of the columns in my table contain a lot of data that rarely needs to be read. Also, disclaimer - this may be Apollo specific because that's what I'm using. Not sure if what I'm doing is in the GraphQL spec.

Here's the approach I took:

1. Pull out `selections` from `info` for the Query.

```
const { selections } = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet;
```

2. Build up `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ProjectionExpression`.

```
  let ExpressionAttributeNames;
  let ProjectionExpression;    
  if (selections) {            
    let current = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
    ExpressionAttributeNames = selections
      .filter(s => !s.selectionSet)  // Skip nested queries
      .reduce((obj, { name }) => {    
        const key = '#' + String.fromCharCode(current++);
        obj[key] = name.value; 
        return obj;            
      }, {});

    ProjectionExpression = Object.keys(ExpressionAttributeNames).join(',');
  }
```

3. Pass in `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `ProjectionExpression` along with other DynamoDB query params. I'm including this for completeness - steps 1 and 2 are the core of this issue.

```
  const params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':foo': foo
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'foo = :foo',
    ProjectionExpression,
    TableName: table
  };

  const response = await db.query(params).promise();
  return response.Items;
```